# HTML form validation issue

Tags: javascript, html, validation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(n,mail,msg)
{
if(name.toLowerCase()== "")
{
alert("Please Enter your name.");
document.getElementById("Name").select();
    document.getElementById("Name").focus();
    return false;
}
else if(lname.toLowerCase()== "")
{
    alert("Please Enter your email.")
    document.getElementById("email").select();
    document.getElementById("email").focus();   
    return false;
}
else if(ph == "")
{ 
    alert("Please Enter your Contact Number.")
    document.getElementById("message").focus();
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

=========================================================

```
<form method="post" name="contact_form" action="contact-form-handler.php">

<p> Your Name:
<input type="text" name="name"></p>

<p>Email Address:
<input type="text" name="email"></p>

<p>Message:
<textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
```

=========================================================

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="return check(document.getElementById('name').value,document.getElementById('email').value,document.getElementById('message').value)" />
```

=========================================================

i am having issues with the HTML validation as when i clicked the button, there is no validation performed.

Comment: I am not quite sure, since I haven't written anything similar. But should not I be just `<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="check(document.getElementById('name').value,document.getElementById('email').value,document.getElementById('message').value)" /> . That is without the `return` word? Also I think the `click()` function does not need to have any arguments, since you can ask for those arguments inside the function.

Comment: There is no element in the form which is having id `email`, `message` and `name`...

Comment: There is no id in the input and textarea. But you are trying to query document.getElementById("name").

Comment: There is no `lname` , `name`, or `ph` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead .. add the validation on the form as below:

```
<form method="post" name="contact_form" action="contact-form-handler.php" 
onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

This works 100% times

Answer (score 0):

try this instead for your button:

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="function(){ check(document.getElementById('name').value,document.getElementById('email').value,document.getElementById('message').value)}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" name="contact_form" action="contact-form-handler.php">

<p> Your Name:
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"></p>

<p>Email Address:
<input type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>

<p>Message:
<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea></p>
```

Use this html markups. It has ids which you have missed. 
You are using document.getElementById("name"). But the input field doesn't have id "name". Same for other fields.